# Резиновый Font.Size текста в TextBox или как лучше организовать красивый и эластичный текст

Tags: c#, winforms

Сразу приведу код:

```
        TextBox te_warning = new TextBox();
        te_warning.Parent = splitContainerControl3.Panel1;
        te_warning.ReadOnly = true;
        te_warning.Multiline = true;
        te_warning.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        te_warning.BackColor = Color.Red;
        te_warning.Font = new Font(te_mat_not_exist.Font.FontFamily, 86);
        te_warning.Font = new Font(te_mat_not_exist.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        te_warning.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        te_warning.Text = "введенные данные не найдены";
```

Вроде все устраивает но проблема в том что у меня на ноуте экран с нормальным разрешением, но программа должна правильно функционировать даже при разрешении экрана 800х600 или еще меньше и выводить сообщение на максимальном размере. А, с размером текста 86 не всегда все слова поместятся и будут видны. Возникла проблема при определении размера TextBox и тем самым уменьшении размеров текста.

У меня основной задачей является красивый вывод текста на панели. Тем самым если есть другой возможность то тоже буду рад советам. Я пока новичок и только начал изучать C#. Так что буду рад за любой совет и помощь.

Comment: это WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Это в WinForms.

Comment: В принципе, этот подход (уменьшение размера шрифта) будет работать, но я не уверен, что шрифты «вразнобой» будут выглядеть хорошо. Например, если несколько раз повторяется одинаковый размер текста, а потом идёт уменьшенный. Возможно, более правильным решением было бы попросить вашего UI-дизайнера пересмотреть интерфейс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение с созданием кастюмного контрола. Код:

```
public class ScalableLabel : Control
{
    public ScalableLabel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        base.AutoSize = false;
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    }

    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get { return false; }
        set { }
    }

    public StringAlignment Alignment { get; set; }
    public StringAlignment LineAlignment { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var sf = new StringFormat(){Alignment = Alignment, LineAlignment = LineAlignment};

        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

        var size1 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);
        var kx = 1f * ClientSize.Width / size1.Width;
        var ky = 1f * ClientSize.Height / size1.Height;
        var k1 = Math.Min(1, Math.Min(kx, ky));

        var size2 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font, ClientSize.Width, sf);
        kx = 1f * ClientSize.Width / size2.Width;
        ky = 1f * ClientSize.Height / size2.Height;
        var k2 = Math.Min(1, Math.Min(kx, ky));

        var k = Math.Max(k1, k2);

        using(var font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size * k))
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, font, brush, ClientRectangle, sf);
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Источник [cyberforum.ru](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1667638.html#post8786713)